# Adding other cells values if text

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to calculate the percentage of hours people are participating and available. People are not always chosen to participate, but should not be penalized if they are available.

Column B is the participation percentage.

Row 2 is the master row with the total number of hours that were available, with their respective dates above in Row 1.

When a person is available but not selected, a lowercase X is placed in their row and on the date.  Ideally, I would like "x" to take on the value of the master row cell of the same column, but retain the appearance of an x, so the range can easily be calculated.

The only way I can see doing this right now is making a separate column (hidden) that would contain an If/then? like: if I$7="x", then(sum(L7+I2) and I don't even know how I would do that, much less across multiple cells.

I thought this would be a cheesy workaround except sometimes the hours aren't always 3, sometimes they're 2.

=SUM(F7/(F2-(3*(COUNTIFS(F7:7,"x")))))

Rows 3 through 7 in the picture, need 100% in Column B.

[Participation spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jz7z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this user defined function. Copy this code into the Script Editor and save it. Then enter =total(row($F2)) in F2 and copy it down to all rows. It sends the row number to the function:

```
function total(ln) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lc=s.getLastColumn()//get the last column with data
  var rng=s.getRange(2, 7, 1, lc-6).getValues()// get row 2 values
  var rng1=s.getRange(ln, 7, 1, lc-6).getValues()// get values of current row
  var count=0 //set count to 0
  for(var i=0;i<rng[0].length;i++){
     if(rng1[0][i]=="x"){// if value is x
       var cnst=rng[0][i]//get row 2 value
       count=count+cnst}//add to count
     else{count=count+rng1[0][i]}}//if not x, added cell value to count
return count // return the total
}
```

The function will expand as new columns are added.

Comment: Thank you so much for this excellent script.  You are a lifesaver.

Comment: You are welcome. If this works for you, please approve the answer by clicking the check to the left of the answer. Thanks.